# Any workaround to save an Intent in settings?

Tags: android

Hope you will understand my question with my basic english...

In my application, I allow the user to have a button that launch the application of his choice. I get no problem to make a list of all installed apps, get the Intent and launch the choosen app.

But I would like to save the corresponding intent in the settings for the next time the user use my application, but settings only allow me to save basic data type ( Integer, boolean, Strings, etc. )

So, my question is how to save an intent in a smart way.

I hope you can help me to find a solution.

Comment: Try this solution based on Gson: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34580505/2267723

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You should use `myIntent.toURI()` to store the `Intent`, and use `Intent.getIntent(String uri)` to restore the `Intent`.

```
public void saveIntent(Intent intent) {
    mSharedPrefs.edit().putString(SOME_KEY, intent.toURI()).commit();
}

public Intent restoreIntent() {
    String uri = mSharedPrefs.getString(SOME_KEY, *mSomeDefaultUri*);
    return Intent.getIntent(uri);
}
```

Comment: Just for info, _toUri()_ is now deprecated. Use **toUri(int flags)** instead.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of saving the `Intent` you could just save the `String` which is necessary to build the `Intent`.

Example:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.notepad.action.EDIT_TITLE");
```

Now you just store a `String` containing `com.android.notepad.action.EDIT_TITLE`