# Create app shortcut inside the Custom Launcher in Android

Tags: android

I'm trying to develop a custom launcher that will contain the shortcut of my installed application (or even apk files). I can create a shortcut BUT outside the application and what I need to do is to create it inside my launcher activity. How can I do that?

**AdminActivity.java** (This activity contains a method that has the ability to create shortcut of the installed app from the device)

```
private boolean installUninstall_ShortCut(Context context, String appName, boolean isTrue) {
    boolean flag =false ;
    int app_id=-1;
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    List<ResolveInfo> res = pm.queryIntentActivities( i,0);


    for(int k=0; k<res.size(); k++) {
        if(res.get(k).activityInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString().equals(appName)){
            flag = true;
            app_id = k;

            break;
        }
    }

    if(flag) {
        ActivityInfo ai = res.get(app_id).activityInfo;

        Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        shortcutIntent.setClassName(ai.packageName, ai.name);
        shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, appName);
        intent.putExtra("duplicate", false);

        if(isTrue) {        
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(context, R.drawable.ic_launcher));
            intent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");       
        } else {
            intent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT");
        }

        context.sendBroadcast(intent);

    } else
        System.out.println("applicaton not found");
    return true;
}
```

**activity_launcher.xml** (This is the Layout of Launcher Activity where the shortcut will go. I really don't know how to bring the created shortcut in this activity)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/plain_without_logo"
    tools:context=".S_2nd_MainActivity" >

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/grid_app"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:columnWidth="80dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:horizontalSpacing="15dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="15dp" />
```

Comment: Hey, did you solve this? can you accept an answer or add the right answer to close this question and get it off the unanswered list, thanks! (You're allowed to answer your own questions)

Answer (score 1):

What you are creating is not a launcher like the home screen, its just an application. The launcher category refers to the activity being listed in the all apps drawer. I don't think applications can add their own shortcuts otherwise spam ware could just keep adding its icon to your home screen like this and annoy every user.

Also installUninstall_ShortCut is not how we name things in Java! Actually it doesn't match any naming convention I've ever come across

If you want to mimic adding-shortcut-like functionality then you can get the grid view and call addView on it

Comment: Sorry, I really don't know the proper naming convention for that.

Comment: That's ok but it wouldn't hurt to study up. Java classes are named with a capital and camelcased, methods start lowercase and are also camelcase. resources are lowercase with underscores http://source.android.com/source/code-style.html#follow-field-naming-conventions

Comment: apps can add their own shortcuts. it's the mechanism some apps use to update their icon, apparently. undocumented though.