# How to save user selected intents?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, class, android-intent

so I'm building a launcher and I need a way of saving Intents.
I am using the following code to get a list of installed applications where the user can select which to run.

Code -

```
         final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
         mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
         final List pkgAppsList = getActivity().getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities( mainIntent, 0);
         startActivity(Intent.createChooser(mainIntent, "Choose your default app"));
```

But I have several buttons, and I'm using this method to let the user choose which application to run. But the problem is I would like these selections made by the user to be saved, for example, when I click the clock button it lets me choose which app I want to run, then it's saved. But I don't know how.

Also I did find a way to do it, I just removed "`Intent.createChooser();`" so that I can select "use default" but when you set it as default, any other button you press  such as the calendar button, it opens the clock button.

I have done lots of research on intents and have gotten all this working but I'm finding it hard to do that above, please if you know a way of making an App Chooser, where the user gets to select which app to launch when a button is pressed and then that intent gets saved so the user doesn't have to keep choosing.

Thanks for your time, hopefully I've asked everything in good manner.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812650/any-workaround-to-save-an-intent-in-settings

Comment: @kupsef Thanks for the reply, but I'm having trouble with doing what's said.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend saving the package name of the app that the user wants as default.

To do this, you should separate the call for `Intent.createChooser` and `startActivity`, then between those two calls, save the package in the intent. For example:

```
Intent intent = Intent.createChooser(...);
String packageName = intent.getPackage();//you might have to play around with the name of the method here.... it is not clear from the docs whether this returns what you want
String action = intent.getAction();//this will return the action that the user wants to preform - this needs to be saved too, so you know when to display the choosing dialog again and when not to
saveChoice(action, packageName);
startActivity(...)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I'm getting loads of errors.

Comment: @Robin - That's because this is not full code - you need to fill in the `...` with whatever the method takes as a parameter, just like you have in you code in the question

Comment: Thanks, I changed the code and used your example as a reference, but I am getting The method saveChoice(String, String) is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){} on saveChoice(action, packageName);

Comment: @Robin - yes - you will need to write a new method to save the choice (I left that out too) - I would recommend taking a look at shared preferences to do this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values