# how to stop an android START.STICKY service after application has been killed and started again

Tags: android, service, background-service

I have a background service for listening location update using FusedAPI.

```
public class ListenLocation extends Service
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
            return Service.START_STICKY;
    } ... //code continues for location listener
```

I am starting this service from inside a fragment using

```
getActivity().startService(new Intent(getActivity(),ListenLocation.class));
```

All this is working fine and i am getting the location updates in background.

But how to stop this service once the application has been closed by the user ?

i tried the following but it's not stopping the service

```
getActivity().stopService(new Intent(getActivity(),ListenLocation.class));
```

What is the method to stop such service ?

Comment: Save the intent somewhere and retrieve and use that same intent to stop it when you restart app

Comment: how to save the intent?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812650/any-workaround-to-save-an-intent-in-settings

Comment: i need it to start sticky so i can get location details even app has been killed

Comment: @TimCastelijns what is wrong with my current approach ?

Comment: I tried to save the intent and then calling the stop service, But it's still not stopping the service..