# How to store intent in sharedpreferences

Tags: java, android

So I searched up how to store Intents into sharedpreferences and I saw this post:

[Any workaround to save an Intent in settings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812650/any-workaround-to-save-an-intent-in-settings)

However, the answer that was proposed in that post used deprecated methods such as

```
Intent.getIntent(String);
```

and

```
Intent.toURI();
```

I was wondering if there were any other ways to store Intents without using these deprecated methods.

Comment: Could you also show your `intent` statement that you used

Comment: I imagine storing a fridge inside a coldroom

Comment: @zjmo sorry, I'm new to android, am I doing something that's impractical?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `toUri(int flags)` as an alternative for `toURI()` and `getActivity().getIntent(String)`  as an alternative for `getIntent(String)`.